How to always keep a feature in XGBoost while using colsample_bytree hyperparameter
I use XGBoost to train an ML model. If I use colsample_bytree hyperparameter, XGBoost treats all features equally. I need one binary feature always included since this feature determines which subsample the observation belongs to. Other features should be randomly included during training as determined by colsample_bytree hyperparameter. How to do this?

There's the feature_weights parameter, but I haven't yet worked out how this interacts with the subsampling (do you set the weight of your feature to 1? all others to 1/m, or 1/(m-1), or something depending on colsample_bytree, ...?)
